# Defining various variables from an SQL database table - better practice?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have a database that looks like this:

```
Name       | WebsitePrice | WebsiteStock |
-----------------------------------------
football   |   20         | Yes          |
-----------------------------------------
basketball |   10         | No           |
-----------------------------------------
hockey     |   30         | Yes          |
-----------------------------------------
```

I want to create 2 variables for each item:

1. price of item
2. stock of item.

This is the shortest way I came up with:

```
$item1 = "football";
$item2 = "basketball";
$item3 = "tennis-ball";

$productList = array();
$products = $mysqli->query("select * from table_products where Name IN ('$item1', '$item2', '$item3')");
if($products){
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products)){
        $productList[$product['Name']]['WebsitePrice'] = $product['WebsitePrice'];
        $productList[$product['Name']]['WebsiteStock'] = $product['WebsiteStock'];
    }
}

//first product: 

$price1 = $productList[$item1]['WebsitePrice']; 
$stock1 = $productList[$item1]['WebsiteStock'];

//second product: 

$price2 = $productList[$item2]['WebsitePrice'];
$stock2 = $productList[$item2]['WebsiteStock'];

//third product: 

$price3 = $productList[$item3]['WebsitePrice'];
$stock3 = $productList[$item3]['WebsiteStock'];
```

It looks pretty messy to me.
Is there any better way to do this? especially if we assume that I might have 20 items and not just 3.

for example, is there a way to skip writing the whole `('$item1', '$item2', '$item3')` line and make that line refer to  number of items that are defined in the first code block?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to echo the fields directly from the DB, then give your fields aliases, like:

```
SELECT Name, WebsitePrice as PriceOfItem, WebsiteStock as StockOfItem from table_products where Name IN ('$item1', '$item2', '$item3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I changed your code into dynamic one:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","test_user","user1234","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//turn items into an array
$item_array = array('football','basketball','tennis-ball');

//implode items, turn into string
//result for this string is football','basketball','tennis-ball
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product_items = array();

$productList = array();
$result = $con->query("select * from table_products where Name IN ('$item_implode')");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $x = 0;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $product_items[$x]["Name"] = $row['Name'];
        $product_items[$x]["WebsitePrice"] = $row['WebsitePrice'];
        $product_items[$x]["WebsiteStock"] = $row['WebsiteStock'];
        $x = $x + 1;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

//can access data by $product_items[index][attribute]
//prints all
for ($i=0; $i < count($product_items); $i++) { 
    echo $product_items[$i]["Name"] . " - ";
    echo $product_items[$i]["WebsitePrice"] . " - ";
    echo $product_items[$i]["WebsiteStock"] . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

The result should be:

```
football - 20 - Yes
basketball - 10 - No
```

You can add items by adding/appending it to $item_array.

Comment: very nice. since if I want the index to start from `1` and not `0`, I changed `$x = 0;` to `$x = 1;` and `$i=0;` to `$i=1;` and `< count` to `<= count`, I guess these are all the necessary changes right?

Comment: @rockyraw yes, you can do that but you will also change the $item_array. Starting from 1 only works if $item_array[0] is empty or does not exist. If $item_array stays the same, first index is always 0. For example you change your array to $item_array = array('1'=>'football','2'=>'basketball','3'=>'tennis-ball'), you should start at 1. But if your array is the same($item_array = array('football','basketball','tennis-ball')), you should always start at 0. In my opinion, it's simpler if you use 0-based arrays. It depends on your preference, really :)

Comment: well, I kept my `$item_array` just like in your code, and it works fine using only the changes if my first comment, in fact, if i will try to echo the `0` index, i will receive an error. so are you sure about that?

Comment: oops, my bad. You were right. Since the array is joined, you can change the index values.