# Is there a way to create an Array from separate rows?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following code:

```
//turn items into an array
$item_array = array('football','basketball','tennis-ball');

//implode items, turn into string
//result for this string is football','basketball','tennis-ball
$item_implode = join("','", $item_array);

//declare an overall array for result
$product_items = array();

$productList = array();
$result = $con->query("select * from table_products where Name IN ('$item_implode')");
```

Let's say that I will have 20 items I want to insert to the array (rather than 3 as in the code) -

Personally, it would be easier for me if I could insert each item in its own row (for example, a row will replace the role of a coma `,`, rather than in the same line, as it will be very long and exceed the screen.

For example, is there a way to make the array something like this:

```
$item_array = array(
'football'
'basketball'
'tennis-ball'
);
```

Comment: You can do that, just don't delete the `,`'s als in your example, keep them

Comment: oh and found this: http://nomad.so/2014/06/stop-abusing-arrays-in-php/

Comment: What do you want to achieve is not clear !

Comment: @HalayemAnis I will like to modify my code occassionally (add or remove more items), and it is easier for me to understand how many items are invlolved if each item has its own row. so just wanted to know if it's possible to have them in rows.

Comment: @Thomas I'm not sure I got the abasement part, is there a better way to create my code in general rather than using array for this task?

Comment: @rockyraw it's just so you know there are other ways that might suit your need more

Comment: @Thomas well I started [that other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582646/defining-various-variables-from-an-sql-database-table-better-practice/34583946) in first place to get some efficient way for what I want to do, would be happy if you have a better recommendation to add to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to do here having the array shown either way makes no odds, you can only use an array as an array but it must have commas separating values else you will get an error.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp